# Java.lang.StackOverflowError in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

After opening eclipse there comes a dialog box with a message

**"home.xml:java.lang.StackOverflowError
 java.lang.StackOverflowError"**

On home.xml Graphical layout there is a message

**The project target (Android 4.4) is still loading.
The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.**

**Below is home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butbday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:background="#0099CC"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bday"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Birthday &amp; Anniversary "
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butrandom"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/random"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#9933CC"
            android:text="Random Invite  " />

        <Button
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/buttarget"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/target"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="#669900"
            android:text="Target Marketing" />

        <Button
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:textSize="20sp"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/butverify"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/verify"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#FF8800"
            android:text="Verify Code" />

        <Button
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/butatten"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/attendance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#CC0000"
            android:text="Attendence" />

        <Button
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/analytics"
            android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/butanalytics"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#296666"
            android:text="Analytics" />

        <Button
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/notice"
           android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/butnotice"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#660066"
            android:text="Notice Board" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/homecover" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LOG DETAILS :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.BundleFile.internalGetResourceURL(BundleFile.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.BundleFile.getResourceURL(BundleFile.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findResourceImpl(ClasspathManager.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalResourceImpl(ClasspathManager.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalResource(ClasspathManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalResource(DefaultClassLoader.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalResource(BundleLoader.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findResource(BundleLoader.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findResource(BundleLoader.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.getResource(DefaultClassLoader.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder.getResource(ContextFinder.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.decodeClasspath(JavaProject.java:912)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.readFileEntriesWithException(JavaProject.java:2496)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.readFileEntries(JavaProject.java:2506)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.readRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:2544)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.getExternalJars(ProjectClassLoader.java:260)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(ProjectClassLoader.java:232)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:76)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:166)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
```

Comment: Can you post your entire error log?

Comment: restart ecclipse and adb and try

Comment: Somewhere it went to infinite loop error. Post your log..

Comment: I started getting this problem since the ADT update

Comment: Check for any recusive calls for methods. post you log please

Comment: log is too long I have added first few lines ..

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflowError for using too many nested views